# Flask forgetting Routes on POST

Tags: python, flask, passenger, wsgi, shared-hosting

I am trying to run a very simple flask-application on a (shared) WSGI server. The code works fine when I run it with the build-in server, but if I try to `POST` to the URL on the production WSGI server, I receive a `404, The requested URL was not found on the server` error.
This only occurs for `POST` requests, `GET` and `PUT` are processed as expected.

By removing the placeholder `tid`, flask can be convinced to properly process the request, but this is obviously not a proper solution.

The server is running Phusion Passenger, the flask version is 1.0.2.
As it is a shared server, I have no further access to the server configuration.

What can cause flask to seemingly forget routes on a WSGI-server?

A minimal example that reproduces to behaviour (on the server only, of course) can be seen below:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.views import MethodView


app = Flask(__name__)

class API(MethodView):
    def get(self, tid=0):
        return "Test"
    def put(self, tid=0):
        return "Test"
    def post(self, tid=0):
        return "Test"

app.add_url_rule("/test/<int:tid>", view_func=API.as_view('api'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the methods you use in `add_url_rule`:

```
app.add_url_rule("/test/<int:tid>", view_func=API.as_view('api'), methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'POST'])
```